# Give a JavaScript function a 'false' option?

Tags: javascript

How do you make a JavaScript function have a false option, which makes sure the function doesn't execute?

Here's the code:

```
    function deleteExtraRows(tableID){
        tableID = '#'+tableID;    
       $(tableID+' tr').each(function(){
            if($(tableID+' tr').length>1){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });

    }
```

I want to also be able to give it a (false) option, so I can run deleteExtraRows(false), which will not make the function run. I know this seems kind-of backwards, but it would fit in the project I'm working on if I can do this.

Please help!

Comment: That function makes no sense with removing the rows and it being in an each. Why not just a selector and remove? `$(tableID+' tr').not(":last").remove();`

Comment: ... or you can just call `deleteExtraRows()` without any arguments, and you basically achieved the same thing as what you wanted to do. That leaves you still with a string concatenation and at least a function call overhead though, but those you *can* optimize.

Comment: This all is true. With more research I've figure out a way to bypass the need for all of this, which seems to move the entire program backwards a step. Thank you all for your comments!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function deleteExtraRows(tableID){
    if(tableID === false)
        return;
    ....
}
```

It is important to use `===` as opposed to `==` since `===` checks the type as well. If tableID were 0 or an empty string, it would evaluate to true and return as well.

Comment: And just 'cause I'm genuinely interested on the topic, would it be better doing it this way, or by checking for the inverse? i.e. `if (tableID !== false) { /* do stuff */ }`?

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan They would both do the same thing, but you'd save an extra line of code that way.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan I's probably just a personal preference at that point, I prefer to return rather than having to tab my code out one more tab.

Comment: @KevinB + @Greg ~ yeah, that's what I thought. Just saw all the answers here gravitating to an early `return` and just thought whether or not there's actually a functional reason for my personal preference of early `return`s. :p

Comment: This does exactly what i need it to do, and allows for less code. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

What you have should already work if there isn't an element on the page with an id of `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
 function deleteExtraRows(tableID){
        if(!tableID)
            return;
        tableID = '#'+tableID;    
        $(tableID+' tr').each(function(){
            if($(tableID+' tr').length>1){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Vega Yours would return even if the tableID is `0` or `"0"`

Answer (score 0):

just do **return**

return stops the execution of the function..

```
function deleteExtraRows(tableID, valid ){
      if(!valid)
         return;
        tableID = '#'+tableID;    
       $(tableID+' tr').each(function(){
            if($(tableID+' tr').length>1){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deleteExtraRows(tableID, doWork){
    if (!doWork) return;
        tableID = '#'+tableID;    
       $(tableID+' tr').each(function(){
            if($(tableID+' tr').length>1){
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

where is it being called?
just do:

```
if(!!tableID) deleteExtraRows(tableID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest Greg's answer above, but thought that you can optimize your code a bit by rewriting it like this:

```
function deleteExtraRows (tableID) {

    if (tableID === false) {
        return;
    }

    $('#' + tableID).find('tr:not(:last)').remove();
}
```

... unless I'm misinterpreting your code there.